# Wouldn't it be nice if we had a Community Bulletin?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, meta

Our site is a bit special and different in some places compared to "regular" sites in the Stack Exchange network.

For example:

- We are are both a Meta and a Main site.
- We have a special API documentation widget in our sidebar
- We have different tabs on our home page.

These are all extra goodies that makes Stack Apps special.

But we are also missing out on one aspect.

The Community Bulletin. You know that widget that shows featured posts from your own site-meta and the über-Meta:

> [image: SO Meta]

We do have a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag but it is of no use except for being able to tag a question with a bit more eye-candy like tag. Not being able to bring a post in front of our visitors' eyes when it is warranted or even needed is something that bothers me a bit.

That is why I asked [Catija](https://stackapps.com/users/50498/catija) if having the community bulletin enabled on Stack Apps is even possible. And that got a kind-of confirmation from [Yaakov](https://stackapps.com/users/23003/yaakov-ellis) with the small caveat that [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts on Stack Apps would not show up :/.

So, here is the question:

- If shining a light on one or two questions is a good idea and the Community Bulletin could offer that functionality, do we ask the Stack Exchange dev team to fix the small bug that prevents the bulletin to work as intended?
- Once the bug is fixed, do we ask a CM to enable it on Stack Apps for the purpose of bringing attention to posts that deserve it?

Thoughts? Counter arguments? Better ideas? There is an answer box below this question that takes 30,000 characters.

Comment: Yes to both bullet points - it seems like the userscripting community is going to get some official recognition, so I suspect StackApps is going to rise in popularity too - having a way to feature certain posts (who knows? Maybe there will be an update to the API one day?) is definitely helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it would. And now you do!

Pushed some improvements for your Community Bulletin experience:

- No more "Stack Apps has no Site.ChildMeta defined" message
- Posts with the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag on Stack Apps will show up in your Community Bulletin

> main and meta too?
> community bulletin
> now is here for you!

Comment: Appreciate the speedy fix for this and the haiku ;)

Answer (score 5):

@Catija just informed us the Community Bulletin is now live. Because Stack Apps is ... special (it's a main site but also its own Meta, just like Meta Stack Exchange), we won't see posts [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) here, but we do have a unique error message as compensation:

[image]

Comment: We have to be special ...

Comment: Well, the absence of `ChildMeta` is certainly featured on Stack Apps :)